# isn't sudo just an unnecessary over-rated show off with no particular use except for finger joint arthritis?

Tags: linux

isn't the usage of `sudo` quite unnecessary?
people say it increases security...but how?...we are adding the sudo user to sudo group and ultimately the command is run with root power...a sudo user can do anything a root user can do, because he is the one who knows root password..then what is the use for sudo except for typing four more letters before every command..if i am right, this helps only in repetetive stress injuries in fingers and hand..
lets just admit it... `sudo` is just unnecessary show off.. its better to `root`

Comment: Search around a bit, there are plenty of discussions, e.g. see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/687251).

Comment: The fact that @suvayu cited something at another site is an indication that this question is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @JeffHolt, some questions can be on-topic on multiple sites. However, this one is not [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was young I helped with a project to replace the roof of an elderly woman's house. I spent most of the day walking around the roof carrying a nail gun. As a safety feature, the nail gun would not fire unless you *both* pressed the trigger *and* depressed the tip of the muzzle. When using the nail gun, I would hold the trigger, and bump the tip at each location where I wanted a nail. When I was done, I took my finger off the trigger. Sometimes, I only needed to nail one spot, so I would place the tip, and pull the trigger to fire a single nail.

In the course of that day, I accidentally bumped the tip into someone's hand, and into someone else's knee. If I had been holding the trigger, I probably would have sent both of them to the hospital.

If you are doing lots of things that need `root` privilege, you can log in as `root`. If you just need to do a couple of things, `sudo` can be useful as well. Just watch out that you don't send a server to the hospital.